# Noise reduction OpenCV skindetection sample

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I'm working on a facedetection app using segmentation of skinpixels with a predefined skinmodel in YCrCb space. 
I'm loosely basing my algorithms of this report; http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=767122&tag=1, by Douglas Chai and King N. Ngan.

I first segment out all skin pixels (see left). 
After that I perform some calculations to reduce the noise (see steps below). It results in a filtered bitmap 1/8th the size of original. Ideally this would be noise free both in face and background area, but it isn't. I have already tried to reduce it by using my density map and then checking neighbouring 3x3 area pixels and eroding/dilating pixel values depending on their neighbours. Then I resize this bitmap and apply the result as a mask on the original image (see right image for result, ignore my censorship).

[image: Left is skin pixel segmentation and right is en result]

[image]

My question is, what methods do you recommend for getting rid of the noise? 
 Also, are there any good methods to get smoother contours ? Ideally I would not like to use "find biggest contour and flood fill", preferably something more sophisticated.

There also seem to be bit of a displacement of the resized mask (it cuts of a bit too much on my right side of the face, and shows a bit too much on the left side). What can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way to do smoother contours is to interpolate your data to a higher resolution using an interpolation scheme. You may look in [openCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html), that will result in smoother transitions between points. 
I hope it will help a little bit. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I've already been using resize() and pyrUp() with different interpolation methods to get the result shown in the picture (INTER_CUBIC seemed to yield the best result so far). I had a look at the documentation but I haven't found anything that would be a better choice so far. Thanks anyways.